# Find the first table row

Tags: jquery

I try to get only the first TR of my table. If I click on the delete button in each rows it works anyway.  I can't get it ! I want to delete the very first row after submiting... All works except the first one! I use the same Id from my SQL for Ids tags for the rows of myTable in order to remove them... Don't know if I'm clear...

```
<table id ="myTable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="scrollTable1">

    <thead class="fixedHeader1">
    <tr>
        <th><center><a href="#">Id</a></center></th>
        <th><center><a href="#">User</a></center></th>
        <th><center><a href="#">Dest</a></center></th>
                    <th><center><a href="#">Msg</a></center></th>
                    <th><center><a href="#">Title</a></center></th>
                    <th><center><a href="#">Date</a></center></th>
                    <th><center><a href="#">Hour</a></center></th>
                    <th><center><a href="#">Langue</a></center></th>
                    <th><center><a href="#">Del</a></center></th>
    </tr>
</thead>

    <tbody class="scrollContent1">

 <?  

      $sql="SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY username";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);          
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

           echo'<tr id="'.$row[messageid].'">                           
           <td><center>'.$row[messageid].'</center></td>               
           <td><center>'.addslashes(utf8_decode($row[username])).'</center></td>
           <td><center>'.addslashes(utf8_decode($row[dest])).'</center></td>
                       <td><center>'.utf8_decode($row[message]).'</center></td>
                       <td><center>'.$row[titre].'</center></td>
                       <td><center>'.$row[date].'</center></td>
                       <td><center>'.$row[heure].'</center></td>
                       <td><center>'.$row[langue].'</center></td>
           <form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="delete_msg_SQL.php" method="POST">

                       <td><center><input type="button" class= "myButton" id="'.$row[messageid].'" value="X"/><input type="button" style="visibility:hidden" id="simple-post"/></center></td>
                       </form>
            </tr>';


  }



 ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Jquery code :

```
<script>

$(function(){
$('.myButton').click(function() {

    var myId = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#ajaxform").append('<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'+ myId + '"/>');             

      // HERE the PROBLEM If I click on the delete button on each rows it works anyway instead of the first one! 
      if ($(this).children('tr:first')) {
        alert('ok');            
      }
      $( '#simple-post' ).click(); 
      $('#'+ myId).remove();        
}); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not really clear on what you're trying to do here... You click the button, and then say `if ($(this).children('tr:first'))`? That's not going to work, a button won't have any children that are table rows.

Comment: Yep you're perfectly right !!! Big mistake ! but can i get from there if this button was clicked on the very first row ?

Comment: Your question is quite ambiguous and anyway, your rendered HTML is not valid, IDs must be unique on document context. And why using IDs here for each row?

Comment: `if ($(this).children('tr:first')) {` -  `$(this)` means the button itself that has no `children`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead of

```
$('#'+ myId).remove();
```

put this code

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove()
```

it will traverse the tree up (from the button element) and remove the first **tr** on the way.

[jQuery closest reference](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

to do your check for the first row please try this

```
var tr = $(this).closest('tr')[0];

if (tr === $('#myTable tr:eq(1)')[0]) {
    alert('you clicked a button in the first row');
}
```

working example here
[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/motay/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: I tried and I have exactly the same problem I can't remove the first one at all and moreover with it I can't submit !!!

Comment: @user3281883 you will be anywhere using invalid HTML. You have firstly to fix it, using unique IDs (or better don't use IDs at all) and btw a FORM element cannot be direct child of a TR.

Comment: @user3281883, the first `tr` contains `th` . Do you need to delete that ? No `myButton` is there for the very first `tr` .

Comment: I did it before and used '$(this).closest('tr').remove()' without ids but I still had the same problem. You're right about the child of the form but about a table ?

Comment: I tried with '$("#myTable tr:nth-child(1)").remove();' and effectively I could remove the first TR (the header) then I incremented by one to get the the second row and it didn't work !

Comment: just added a working example that alerts OK, when the first row is clicked. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I removed the ids of my rows and now I'm using `$(this).closest('tr').remove(); $('#simple-post').click();` everything is ok but of course I can't submit my very first row because if it is deleted it's not possible ...lol How can I manage that ?  I I reverse those 2 lines I can submit but not delete !!!

Comment: delete it after the submission

Comment: I really think it is not possible to delete the first row in a table . I have only 2 choices.... remove the row but in this case no submit... or submit without delete the row (gonna make a workaround for that like remove the table..)

Comment: I tried Vitaly to reverse the 2 lines of codes  : submit, then delete the submission works but not the delete !

Comment: you can trigger post manually after deletion of a row

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete_msg_SQL.php",
        data: { id: $(this).attr('id') }
})

Comment: That's exacly what I'm doing !!! after the submit the code goes in a php page . If no more messages I'm gonna remove the row!

Comment: You had a better idea this way Vitally, but I can't reach my page with your code ?

Comment: Can I trigg this way with my variable simple-post (I use Ajax to send back some infos to refresh some elements)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Ok, then this:

```
NodeList.prototype.indexOf = function(x){
 for(var i=0;i<this.length;i++) if(this[i] == x) return i;
 return -1;
}
function del(o){ 
 var table = o.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
 var row = o.parentNode.parentNode;
 table.deleteRow(table.childNodes.indexOf(row));
}
...
...<td><input type="button" value="Delete row" onclick="del(this);" /></td>...
```

**Edit MK II :** Ok, try leaving that prototype extension, but changing the del function to this:

```
function del(o){ 
 var table = o.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
 var row = o.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
table.deleteRow(table.childNodes.indexOf(row));
}
```

And then your table cell with the Delete button should look like this:

```
<td><center><input type="button" class= "myButton" id="'.$row[messageid].'" value="X" onclick="del(this);"/>...
```

Comment: this will remove the header, should be `.deleteRow(1);`

Comment: Um, yeah, sorry, I might have invested a not exactly sufficient time period into reading his source. ^^

Comment: this will remove the first row in the table, but the row which includes button needs to be removed.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand it quite right before. And it was supposed to be just a hint - now here's a whole function that should do what I think you are after.

Comment: I can reach the function and check with an alert but nothing is deleted !

Comment: New update. I haven't noticed you have nested the values with a Center element. That added up for more parents. I have tested this with your table structure, so hopefully... it could work.

Comment: Glad to be of help.^^